# Алгоритм списка узлов при обходе в обратном упорядочении

Tags: алгоритм, дерево, графы

Пишу курсовую работу, но есть проблема в недостатке учебных материалов.
Тема "Алгоритм списка узлов при обходе в обратном упорядочении".
Хочу попросить вас помочь в поиске, а так же указать направление движения для максимально быстрого и качественного усвоения этой темы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я так понимаю, что имеется двоичное дерево, которое требуется обойти обратным обходом (или еще говорят правым) и полученную последовательность узлов организовать в список.

На [wiki](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0), в общих чертах, можно узнать про бинарные деревья и алгоритмы с ними связанные.

Еще посоветую найти книгу: "Алгоритмы. Построение и анализ" Кормен, Лейзарсон, Ривест, Штайн. Там подробно описаны структуры данных, в том числе и двоичные деревья, и алгоритмы для работы с ними (алгоритмы приведены со строгим доказательством, которое, думаю, приветствуется в курсовой работе).

Comment: Я в этой тее новичок, поэтому задам возможно глупый вопрос:
Деревья и бинарные деревья это одно и то же?

Comment: Нет, это не одно и то же. Если сказать по простому, то у каждой вершины (узла) дерева может быть сколько угодно подвершин (подузлов или детей), а у каждой вершины бинарного дерева ни одного, один или два. Посмотри здесь http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE_(%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Comment: Ага,спасибо, с этим разобрался.
Но мне нужны именно деревья, обычные. Буду искать :)

Comment: Оо, обычные значит. Рекомендовал бы посмотреть вышеприведенную книгу, там есть глава про B-деревья, которые являются обобщением бинарных, у узлов таких деревьев может быть множество дочерних узлов. Обходов таких деревьев в книге нет. Обойти его конечно можно, если узлы будут упорядочены по соответствующему критерию. Обычно обратный (как и прямой и симметричный) обход ассоциируются с бинарными деревьями. В любом случае, удачи тебе в поисках! :)

Comment: Хотя, возможно деревья и бинарные, т.к. другие темы как раз для обратного, прямого и симметричного обхода, что, как вы сказали, больше похоже на бинарные деревья.